# get json array from servlet using ajax

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, json, jsp

I have to json array in my servlet.

I want to fetch json array value and print in to jsp page using ajax.

below is code

```
JSONArray  htags = new JSONArray();
        htags.add("#abc");
        htags.add("#xyz");
        htags.add("#emc");
        htags.add("#netapp");


        //top trends
        JSONArray trends = new JSONArray();
        trends.add("pass");
        trends.add("horiz");
        trends.add("software");
        trends.add("banana");
```

**jsp**

I got error msg here.

```
$.ajax({

            url : "SerlvetToJsp",
            dataType : 'json',
            error : function() {

                alert("Error");
            },
            success : function(data) {
                alert(data);

            }
    });
```

Comment: What is the error message ?

Comment: I got "error" dialog box. and in my servlet I only write above code nothing much. please help

Comment: How are you passing back the result??
can you add your JSP code...

Comment: What is your browser  console saying ??

Comment: The url don't seem right, you see anything on firebug or any console?

Comment: @gjman2 he is not getting the result, that is for parsing the result.

Comment: Try with `url : "/SerlvetToJsp"`

Comment: But how to get Json array I wrote only code which I write in code\

Comment: @Nick Are you asking how send result(that json array) to ajax from servlet

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ: Like that. But want to fetch from servlet and display in jsp page

Comment: You are confused I guess,wrote the answer .")

Answer (score 0):

See, if you want to pass that from servlet to jsp you need not to make a `request` (ajax), since servlet and `jsp` both exists at server side.You just set that json array  as a request attribute or session attribute and get it in jsp and display(with loop).**NO** need of ajax there.

If You need to fetch the data with synchronous call:

In servlet

```
   PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
   out.println(htags);
```

I won't clutter SO with another full example,see this SO post:[How to send JSON array from server to client, i.e. (java to AJAX/Javascript)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083951/how-to-send-json-array-from-server-to-client-i-e-java-to-ajax-javascript)

Comment: I as per requirement have to used ajax. can u explain how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

### servlet code

```
JSONArray  htags = new JSONArray();
        htags.add("#abc");
        htags.add("#xyz");
        htags.add("#emc");
        htags.add("#netapp");


        //top trends
        JSONArray trends = new JSONArray();
        trends.add("pass");
        trends.add("horiz");
        trends.add("software");
        trends.add("banana");
response.setContentType("application/json"); 
response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8"); 
String jsons = "["+htags+","+trends+"]"; //Put both objects in an array of 2 elements
out.print(jsons);
```

and on you jsp page

```
$.ajax({

            url : "SerlvetToJsp",
            dataType : 'json',
            contentType:"application/json",
            error : function() {

                alert("Error");
            },
            success : function(data) {
                var data1=data[0],
                var data2=data[2],
               alert(data1[0]);

            }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Servlet can use this to send json array or json object to client.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = [{:}, {:}];

response.getWriter.write(jsonArray.toString());
```

In JSP page, this method call the request JSON to Servlet and catch the json array or json object with annonymous function(JSON.parse is used to convert string to json object or json array) method.

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $.get("ServletToJSP",function(data,status){
    alert("Data: " + JSON.parse(data) + "\nStatus: " + status);
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

in servlet:

```
String uri = request.getRequestURI();
        if (uri.equalsIgnoreCase(uri)) {
                    response.setContentType("application/json");
                    /*   get the json array      */
                    response.getWriter().write(array.toJSONString());
                }
```

jquery:

```
    $('#buttonid').on('click', function() {
           var url="your url";
        $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url : url,
                data : null,
                error : function(xhr, status, error) {
                    alert("error");
                },
                success : function(data) {
                    alert("success");
                    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                    console.log(val);
                }
            });
    });
```